# Oracle - Records from multiple tables with * parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to retrieve the records from multiple different views. The views have exactly the same columns. I want to use the * parameter because there are constantly added new views and with `UNION ALL` there would be always the same code.

Whats working:

```
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE3
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE4
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE5
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE6
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM TABLE7
```

What I want:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE6
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE7´
```

If I do that, I get the following error:

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

**UPDATE**:

Ok sorry, my fault.
The views weren't exactly the same because one datatype was converted to a number and the other to a varchar.
Problem solved.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Remember that the UNION's different selects must have the same number of columns, with matching data types.

Comment: the tables are exactly the same but with different data

Comment: Then you can do `select *`. But why do you have so many similar tables?

Comment: That are views, not tables. These views are build up with completely different parameters but same columns

Answer (score 0):

if both tables have exactly same number column and datatype it should work
see below example

```
with cte1 (st,dt) as 
(
select 'New' as st, '30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Open' as st, '30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Open' as st, '20/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Qued' as st, '18/06/2015 1:31:30' as dt from dual

)
,
 t2(st,dt) as
 (
 select 'New' as st, '30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Open' as st, '30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Open' as st, '20/09/2014 3:48:10 PM' as dt from dual
union all
select 'Qued' as st, '18/06/2015 1:31:30' as dt from dual
 )
select * from cte1
union all 
select * from t2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=430f00a6616515f2cdaefe61990285d0

Comment: i got the following error 
`ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`

Comment: @ThomasKlammer yes i said my answer column data type should be same

Comment: i copied the views. those are the same

Comment: @ThomasKlammer https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=430f00a6616515f2cdaefe61990285d0 chek this

Comment: As an aside, `'30/09/2014 3:48:10 PM'` is not a date it is a string. If you want a `DATE` data type then wrap it in the `TO_DATE` function or use literals (either a `DATE` literal and add an `INTERVAL` literal or a `TIMESTAMP` literal and cast back to a `DATE`).

Answer (score 0):

> The views weren't exactly the same because one datatype was converted to a number and the other to a varchar.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc390/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
  id    NUMBER(8,0),
  text  VARCHAR2(400),
  value NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
  id    NUMBER(8,0),
  text  VARCHAR2(200),
  value VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 1, '1', 1 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 2, '2', '2' );
```

**Query 1**: If the data types do not match then you will get an exception:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc390/1/1)**:

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

**Query 2**:

To solve this, you can use `SELECT * FROM ...` on the tables with the matching data types and explicitly name columns and apply a conversion on the table(s) that have different data types:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, text, TO_NUMBER( value ) FROM TABLE2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc390/1/0)**:

```
| ID | TEXT | VALUE |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 |    1 |     1 |
|  2 |    2 |     2 |
```